# What is STRIPS in artificial intelligence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a homework in artificial intelligence.
I need to make a robot go from room A to room B and there are obstacles between the rooms.
The professor asked me to use STRIPS (Stanford Research Institute Problem Solver) but I can not understand how STRIPS works. 
Can someone give me a good explanation and examples about what is strips and how it work?
Thank you.

Comment: I did not ask my professor because he took my Chicken pet as a hostage and said if you ask me what STRIPS is I will kill the chicken soo I can not ask him.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvsmkKk6weE

Comment: Anything else to add? Please add some pseudo-code or a small attempt. I would check youtube for STRIPS tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please note, this is based on what I half-remember from nearly a year ago]

These days, I would expect that when the Prof. says STRIPS, they would be talking about the problem coding 'language', rather than the planner - check for example the Wikipedia page:  [STRIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS).  I would imagine that your Prof. likely has a particular solver (and quite possibly algorithm too) in mind, and is wanting you to encode the domain and specific problem, to run on the solver.  Without knowing more details of the assignment, I can't be sure what you need.  If you're looking for a planner, as I understand it, [Fast Downward](http://www.fast-downward.org/HomePage) is quite popular among researchers currently.  The website has some instructions on how to use it, and IIRC it comes with a bunch of domains and problems for those domains.  I would thoroughly recommend looking at those, they're pretty much what I learnt with.  I also just found [this](https://stripsfiddle.herokuapp.com/) and [this](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~degiacom/didattica/dottorato-stavros-vassos/AI&Games-Lecture6-part1.pdf).

STRIPS is essentially a way of encoding information about the nature of the problem you want the computer to find a solution to.  Typically you encode a domain, which provides information about the problem overall, such as what objects may be involved, what states they can be in, and what actions can be taken.  Then, you also encode a particular problem, which (generally) specifies the starting state of the problem, and what the goal state should look like.  Both those files are fed into a solver, which takes them and then finds a solution to the problem.  Note that this won't always necessarily be an optimal solution - that depends on what algorithm you use, and how you have told the solver what should be optimised (which I think you can generally do in the problem, though I can't remember for sure now).

I suggest you have a look at those links, and see what you can find out.  That should hopefully give you a better idea of what gaps you need filled in your knowledge, and then you can narrow in on exact specifics.  If this is a taught course assignment, then I would expect that surely the Prof. would have gone over some of this in lectures (do you have lecture slides available?), or at least pointed everyone towards a recommended planner and material to read up on.  If you're still struggling, your best bet is to go back and see the Prof. in office hours.